# How can two ListViews share a common view within list elements?

Tags: android, android-layout

Update: In Android it appears that (correctly if I am wrong), a view must have exactly one parent in order to be displayed. This differs from a lot of other UI systems in not allowing a view to be shared. Could someone confirm if this is the case?

I have an ad view (yeah I don't like ads either), which needs to appear in two separate list views.  How can both list views include this common ad view? (the ad view is maintained by the activity and not by the list adapters). When I add to one it is removed from the other because if I do an add it says it can only have one parent. So I remove the parent which happens to be the holder in the other list view. So the ad ends up appearing in only one list at a time.  But more generally how can two separate views each contain another view which is common to both?

Just for simplification if I have two views, v1 and v2 and there is a third view v3 which is a FrameLayout containing an image and text.  How should I reference this v3 from v1, and v2.  Do I just do an include of v3 in v1 and v3? Its a particular instance of V3 that I want both to point to?

Here is the ad I want to share my_ad.xml (please note its created/inflated/updated by the MainActivity and not the ListAdapters):

```
<FrameLayout     android:id="@+id/myAd">
   <ImageView></ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my list_view_1_row

```
<RelativeLayout>
 ......
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myAdHolder" />
     <include
    android:id="@+id/myAdInclude"
    layout="@layout/my_ad" />
 </LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
```

Here is list_view_2_row

```
<RelativeLayout>
 ......  .... 
 ......
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myAdHolder" />
     <include
    android:id="@+id/myAdInclude"
    layout="@layout/my_ad" />
 </LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
```

So now lets say that I inflate my_ad.xml and keep a reference to it in my MainActivity

```
   private FrameLayout myAdd;

   onCreate()
      myAd = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(my_ad.xml)
```

Now what I need to know is how do I now share this view INSTANCE (that was inflated by the activity and whose content is managed by the activity) in elements of the two list views? How do I set it within the adapters of the list views.  If I add it  I get issues about View must not have more than one parent. When I try to just get a reference to the View within the row item. How can I set the ViewHolder value in my adapter to this common view Instance?

I am managing the ad within my activity, and not in the ListAdapters so I wanted to share the Activity managed view within two separate lists that each have their own adapter.

BTW, the other thing I tried beside adding the adding the adView in was was to try to get a reference to myAdInclude within the adapter but this returned as null.  Still I would need to really set the value somehow ......

I also would like comments/opinions about how to maintain a view that is shared by two or more listviews/adapters when its creation/update of the views content does not logically belong exclusively to either list view? Will the list views automatically update when the contained view is updated?

Comment: Don't have the option right now. I have a base class for activity which cannot extend from Fragment right now.

Comment: 35+ views. 1 comment, and 1 downvote.

Comment: Is it just me or it seems like when you post real code, and discuss an actual issue, people do not pitch in.  Ask something generic and folks are all over it.  But give any indication its a real issue for you and there is often much less response.

Comment: 50+ views, 1 comment, and one downvote.  No upvotes for my research and answer!  what does this say!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are not generally sharable in Android because in order to be displayed they must have exactly one parent view at a time.